# Can't pick up a field created with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, image-gallery, advanced-custom-fields

I have a situation where:

- I need to create a custom link per image on an image gallery. I did that via [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com). I have created a text field with HTML outputing so that hyperlinks get converted automatically.
- The user will be populating that field with the link every time a new post is created.
- I am using a custom post type (post-portfolio).
- Each post has a cover image that will be a thumbnail when looking at the gallery.
- Those links will later on be displayed as a link on the thumbnail of the image - not on the image's lightbox or single-post page.
- The gallery's default behavior is to have two font-awesome icons acting as buttons/links: Lightbox view and single post permalink. I have now added a new font awesome link/button to have that text field acting as the link's target.

The code on the functions.php:

```
if(function_exists("register_field_group"))
{
    register_field_group(array (
        'id' => 'acf_sponsorer-lank',
        'title' => 'Sponsor hyperlänk',
        'fields' => array (
            array (
                'key' => 'field_56ea5ece13165',
                'label' => 'Sponsor länk till webbsida',
                'name' => 'sponsor_lank_till_webbsida',
                'type' => 'text',
                'instructions' => 'Skriv här webbsidan till sponsorn. Om det inte finns någon webbsida skriv endast #',
                'required' => 1,
                'default_value' => '',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'prepend' => '',
                'append' => '',
                'formatting' => 'html',
                'maxlength' => '',
            ),
        ),
        'location' => array (
            array (
                array (
                    'param' => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'post-portfolio',
                    'order_no' => 1,
                    'group_no' => 1,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'options' => array (
            'position' => 'normal',
            'layout' => 'default',
            'hide_on_screen' => array (
            ),
        ),
        'menu_order' => 0,
    ));
}
```

The code on the gallery that shows all thumbnails:

```
$variable = get_field('sponsor_lank_till_webbsida', $post->post-portfolio);

<div class="acts">
    <h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3>
    <a href="'.$url.'" title="'.get_the_title().'" class="icon-search" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><!----></a>
    <a href="'.the_field('sponsor_lank_till_webbsida', get_option('acf_sponsorer-lank')).'" class=" icon-h-link" target="_blank"><!----></a> <!-- the link where the problem is -->
    <a href="'.get_permalink().'" class=" icon-link"><!----></a>
</div>
```

A note on the last bit of code I wrote:

The `<div class="acts">` is inside of PHP tags, so no need to open and close it there.

### Problem

The custom field is showing up where on the custom post type page when the admin creates a new post, but the link on the gallery page has no target (the value that the user inserts on the post creation page).

I have been reading the documentation and trying so many times and so many ways but I cannot seem to make it work.

Comment: Try searching for answers with `acf_local_field_group` instead

Comment: Thanks @Damien! After some search I did not find any information about acf_local_field_group, neither via Google or ACF documentation. What I did find was `get_field_object`. So, after reading it I tried it. I wrote `$field_name = field_56ea5ece13165; $sponsor_url = get_field_object($selector, $post_id, $format_value, $load_value);` (only defined $field_name since the others have a default value). The result is still the same. Either I am approaching this in the completely wrong way or something else is not allowing me to get what I want... Any other suggestions?